# supportedInterfaceOrientations - Supporting iOS6 and iOS5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, rotation, ios6

Just a quick question. Say I have updated my app to iOS6 and changed the shouldAutoRotate methods of iOS5 as follows :

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

If I am still supporting iOS5, do I need to check for the iOS version and then also include the old iOS5 methods (i.e shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation) if the app is being run on a device running iOS5 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ok to have both iOS5 and iOS6 code in your app.

On iOS5, supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate will not be called, and on iOS6 the old methods shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation etc will not be called.

Comment: Ah great - thanks. I wonder if eventually the old iOS5 version will be flagged as deprecated when compiling.

Comment: I would expect this to happen around iOS7 or so